# Play Framework 2.3.x scala - Application shutdown without exception

Tags: java, scala, unix, playframework, jvm

I have a play framework 2.3 application. When I deploy it my local machine in dev or production mode it works perfectly fine. However, when I deploy in a different server (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2, Santiago), after around 2 hours the application shuts down.
After profiling the application several times, I concluded that there aren't memory issues, deadlocks, etc. Everything is normal. I'm overriding the onStop method from GlobalSettings and logging a message like this:

```
 override def onStop(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application is shutting shutdown...ByeBye")
  }
```

and in the logs this is all what I see before the shutdown:

```
2015-05-27 00:36:54,515 - [INFO] - from application in **Thread-4** 
Application is shutting shutdown...ByeBye
```

For some reason, it always come from Thread-4. 
I have the log in DEBUG level and I don't see any exceptions or messages that could raise any red flag. It seems that something is killing the application or sending a signal to stop. I have not been able to determine the reason of this shutdown. There isn't anything being logged to /var/log/messages or any other log besides the one of my application.
Any ideas that could lead me to understand why the application stops?

Some details of my application:
It is very simple, it exposes a REST API. I'm building a binary file and all its dependencies using the 'dist' command. I start it this way:

```
/path/to/binary -Dhttp.port=5000  -J-Xmx32g -Dconfig.resource=application_prod.conf
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure 32 gigs of maximum heap size is ok?

Comment: Yes, it is. The server where I'm deploying has hundreds of RAM available and my app uses much less than 32gb. I profiled and see that memory is fine and it is not the cause of the shutdown.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. In my case, I don't even know why the server is getting shut down and the overridden method `onStop` doesn't get called.

Comment: are you using akka in your play application ?

Answer (score 1):

There's an [known issue providing java opts via `-J` parameter](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3688). Try `JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx32g" ./activator` instead.
After doing this, check your running process list to approve if the java opts are really there.

Answer (score 0):

If you've been starting your application from the terminal via ssh ,after a while the ssh session might get terminated and the application process is attached to the session process ,
I went around this by executing the start command via nohup so the process will not be interactive anymore and will output the logs to the specified file instead of the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, apparently when running in debug mode ("run" command instead of "start" for production) it used to shutdown without exceptions after 4 seconds. Switching to prod. mode solved my problem.